# D3.js log scale stacked bar

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am trying to construct a single column stacked bar chart with d3.js, my data array might look like this in some instances:
[{x: 0, y:1, y0: 0}, {x: 1, y: 10, y0: 1}, {x: 2, y:2, y0: 11}]
but in another instance it might look like this:
[{x: 0, y:20, y0: 0}, {x: 1, y: 300, y0: 20}, {x: 2, y:2189, y0: 320}]

I am having trouble with the log scale. The chart's height is always 150px and the rectangles for the stacked chart should not be smaller than 10px ever.

Comment: This sounds like you would want to compute a custom scale based on the data.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff this is what I'm trying to do currently but am not getting the desired result: var y = d3.scale.log().domain([10, 1000]).range([0, height]);

Comment: I mean a custom scale function, not just input and output domains, i.e. a function that maps input to output values and satisfies your constraints.

Comment: How can I go about doing that, I have no clue where to start....

Comment: You could have a look at the source code for the existing scales for example. I'm not sure if what you want is really feasible though -- would you want to show a rectangle of size 10px for a value of 0?

Comment: Not really, if the value is 0 it should stay zero but if the value is 1 than the rectangle that represents it shoould be at least 10px high. I hope that makes sense, basically I'd like to be able to fill out the entire area 150px high no matter what values come in be it very small or a mix of small and large numbers.

Comment: How about a log scale that maps 1 to 10 and the sum of all values to 150 then?